# Sum all odd digits in a number in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

Is there a built in function in PostgreSQL to sum the alternate digits starting from right hand side?

```
Input: 890400021003
Output:
3 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 4 + 9 = 18 
0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 8 = 9
```

Basically I want to print each alternate numbers and sum it up as above, please advice for any solution in Postgres

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the db, rather than calculating this in the application?

Comment: Because I want to use modulo 10 algorithm on a number randomly for card number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postres 9.4, you can do this easily with a string, using `string_to_array()` and `unnest() with ordinality`:

```
select ord % 2, sum(val::numeric)
from (select reverse('890400021003'::text) as x) x, lateral
     unnest(string_to_array(x, NULL)) with ordinality u(val, ord)
group by ord % 2;
```

In 9.3 you can do this with a lateral join:

```
select i % 2, sum(substring(x.x, g.i, 1)::numeric)
from (select reverse('890400021003'::text) as x) x, lateral
     generate_series(1, length(x.x)) g(i)
group by i % 2;
```

And you can apply the same idea using a subquery in earlier versions.

Comment: `(length(x) - ord) % 2` to satisfy the requirement "starting from right hand side"

Comment: @Abelisto . . . Good catch.  I chose to just reverse the string.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your solution, am checking it. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit version

Comment: I happen to be running 9.5.4 at the moment, and both versions worked.